# rsWrongItemType error for reportViewer in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am trying to view SSRS report in my ASP.net web site through ReportViewer

I managed to get this working for one of the SSRS servers

but the other one gives me this error

> The operation you are attempting on item '/abcdef/hijjk lmno' is not
>   allowed for this item type. (rsWrongItemType)

I tried diifferent solutions provided by social.msdn.microsoft.com but non is working

This is the ReportViewer

```
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" Font-Names="sans-serif" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="457px" BackColor="White" Visible="False" SplitterBackColor="164, 0, 70">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

anyone can help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ReportName has to be part of the ReportPath